# Removing duplicates from a table using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Appreciate if someone can help me out removing duplicates from the table below;

Let us assume that the table name is "t".

```
Row#  col1  col2  col3        col4       col5  col6
1     101   AR12  -           -          -     -
2     101   AR12  faultyPCBA  supplier   1     0.002%
3     327   AR12  -           -          -     -
4     327   AR09  faulty      personnel  5     0.2%
5     327   AR09  faulty      personnel  5     0.2%
6     327   AR09  faulty      personnel  5     0.2%
```

Duplicates in my table are defined if the combination of col1 and col2 are unique. However if there is a value in col3/4/5/6 I would prefer if that was shown rather than blank, thus the final output of the table must look like;

```
Row#  col1  col2  col3        col4       col5  col6
1     101   AR12  faultyPCBA  supplier   1     0.002%
2     327   AR12  -           -          -     -
3     327   AR09  faulty      personnel  5     0.2%
```

Appreciate if you could explain what the code is doing too.

Comment: If you can, please tag which `DBMS` you are using. (`Oracle`, `SQL Server`, etc. It will help us provide a demo for you)

Comment: Thank you Jerry, i have added it is oracle

Comment: How are you defining duplicates?

Comment: duplicates in my table are defined if the combination of col1 and col2 are unique. However if there is a value in col3/4/5/6 i would prefer if that was shown rather than blank.

Comment: Does `-` mean no value?

Comment: yep correct Jerry, "-" means no value

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Looks like you'll want to group by col1 and col3 and then probably select max of the other columns.  Depends a bit on whether you want values from any of the col3/4/5/6 or if you want the col3/4/5/6 from a single not-blank row.  How do you choose which row to get date from for col3/4/5/6 . . .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
from t;
```

Or you may want aggregation:

```
select col1, col2, max(col3), max(col4), max(col5)
from t
group by col1, col2;
```

Comment: Hello Gordon thanks for your reply, unfortunately when i used distinct it leaves a duplicate of row#1 and 2

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the `DISTINCT` keyword...

I don't know your table name, but the following query should work if you replace `tbl` with your table name.

[You can read more about `DISTINCT` here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

`DISTINCT` only selects the *distinct* rows, or essentially, non duplicative rows. So if you have something in there more than once, it is only selected one time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tbl
```

You can see an example of `DISTINCT` with this data here, on [SQL FIDDLE.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3c9f0/1)

Comment: Hello Jerry thanks for your reply, unfortunately when i used distinct it leaves a duplicate of row#1 and 2

Comment: Define _duplicate_. Those rows are not duplicate, they have different values in them. How am I to know which of the two to pick?

Comment: thanks Jerry, duplicates in my table are defined if the combination of col1 and col2 are unique. However if there is a value in col3/4/5/6 i would prefer if that was shown rather than blank

Answer (score 1):

you can use `row_number()` to get at least 1 for each partition

```
select * from
(select *, row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by row_number) as rn
  from t) t1
where t1.rn = 1
```

Comment: This assumes it was sorted correctly. We don't know anything about a sort order. Also, you missed writing `t1` after your subquery :)

Comment: appreciate your time in helping me out Metal! Unfortunately it does not give the expected output that i want.

Comment: @ARJ, `partition by col1, col2` should get desired results

Answer (score 1):

I think analytical function will be useful here.

```
select * from
(select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by col3, col4, col5, col6) as rn
  from t)
where rn = 1
```